# Clipboard Occassionally is Empty on ScreenCapture Loop

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word, clipboard, screen-capture

I have a loop that performs the following tasks:

1. Loops through a series of accounts, and clicks through webpages for each account
2. When it reaches a certain page, captures the screen of the webpage
3. Copies the screen capture to a word document
4. Prints the word document

Most of the time the code works perfectly, but occasionally I get the following error in the middle of processing on the `.Selection.Paste` line in my code below:

> Run-Time error '4605':
>   This method or property is not available because the Clipboard is empty or not valid.

I have tried to solve the problem by putting some `Sleep` commands in my code and by clearing the Clipboard after each copy / paste. My thought is that perhaps the code is moving too fast and the computer needs time to catch up, but no matter how I manipulate how much time it sleeps I can't get the error to stop popping-up at (seemingly) random times.

Does anyone have any ideas to avoid getting this error?

### Here is the code:

```
'... code that loops through accounts and takes and actions against certain webpages until I get to the page I need to print

    Sleep 5000 'pause before screencapture takes place and make sure IE is active

    ScreenCapture

    Sleep 5000 'wait for screencapture to catch up ?

    With wApp 'wApp is a previously set variable that refers to MS Word
        .Visible = True
        .Documents.Add
        .Selection.Paste
        .PrintOut Range:=wdPrintCurrentPage
        .ActiveDocument.Close False
    End With

   Sleep 100   'wait for printing to finish ?

   ClearClipboard

   '... code continues to next account
```

other relevant code ...

```
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)
Public Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long
Public Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32" () As Long

Sub ScreenCapture()
 keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, 0, 0
 keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 1, 0, 0
 keybd_event VK_SNAPSHOT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
 keybd_event VK_MENU, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0
End Sub

Public Function ClearClipboard()
    OpenClipboard (0&)
    EmptyClipboard
    CloseClipboard
End Function
```

*One more note*: I tried printing the IE page directly, but that did not work for reasons not relevant to this post, but I wanted to deter any suggestions to do that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually DoEvents can help in similar situations, in this case before ScreenCapture And/Or after ClearClipboard

Comment: thanks ... will try that tomorrow and see how it works after a few rounds of testing ...  didn't think of that

Comment: sorry, I never answered this until now. the `DoEvents` works like a charm :)